# как работать с браузером через c#?

Tags: c#

Хочу сделать программу для эмуляции работы пользователей, например на сайт, выполняет поиск через заполнение значение инпута и нажатие какой либо кнопки или через консоль разработчика аля например если в google.com то выполнится поиск значения `document.querySelector('input[name=q]').value='привет'; document.querySelector('.gNO89b').click();` не знаю какими инструментами надо пользоваться

Comment: За вас уже все сделано -https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selenium

Comment: selenium, anglesharp / html agility pack, а то и в сторону auto it посмотреть.

Comment: Не используйте селениум сразу, как основной инструмент! Проанализируйте нужный сайт, посмотрите, как он работает, ибо в большинстве случаев достаточно отправить просто POST/GET запрос на определенный адрес. Сам селениум, это как поехать за продуктами, в магазин, который у вас через дорогу, на танке. Он избыточен, вы тянете уйму лишнего с собой и ваше приложение превращается в монстра, который базируется на движке браузера, это во многоб бред! Помните, что селениум, это инструмент тестирования, а не автоматизации!

Comment: спасибо ребят, изначально говорили сделать на BROWSER AUTOMATION STUDIO, думал что есть и полегче вариант:d

Comment: Как вариант, если нужно встроить браузер и дергать из под него что угодно, классная штука [CefSharp](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp)

Comment: цефШарп плохой вариант потому что это именно что встроенный браузер. Там делать это во много раз сложнее чем в селениуме. Кроме того это тот же танк, про который писал ЕвгенийЗет. Пост-Гет запросы идеальный вариант практически всегда.